# ASp.Net MVC site on IIS, 500 error for just CSS files

Tags: asp.net, iis, hosting

I've Uploaded my website on a shared hosting but I get http 500 error just for my css files, other static files are OK, any insight on how I can approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After a day of investigating I found out that in my web.config there was a section like this:

```
<location path="Content" allowOverride="false">
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
       <allow users="?,*" />
     </authorization>
     <trust level="Full" />
   </system.web>
</location>
```

removing `<trust level="Full" />` solved the problem for me

turning on failed request tracing helped me a lot because I saw that there is a configuration error when I want to request a css file so it might help you on another similar case

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.